# Is there any way to get Google Assistant to work on CM13 x86?

Tags: windows, xposed-framework, android-x86, virtualbox, google-assistant

I have tried everything. Installed CM13, got Xposed to work. Installed Assistant enabler, Android N-ify. Tried more versions. x86_64, CM14 (Kept constantly rebooting), Pure Android N. Nothing. Spent more than 8 hours on this. I'm Using VirtualBox on Windows 10.

Does anybody know an actual way to work this out?

Comment: Google assistance doesn't work on Android 6.0 and above. What version are you using?

Comment: 6.0.1. But my Galaxy Nexus have the same version of Cyanogenmod and the Assistant works flawlessly.

Comment: It may work on custom roms but STOCK roms may not work flawlessly